# How To Export Only A Part Of SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

I'm very new to working with SSRS, and currently have an already created SSRS Report that displays a table of values. These values are grouped by an ID that can then be expanded if the user wants it. Basically, I'm looking for a way that I can export that row, and it's grouped data.

I know reports can entirely be exported by default, but I haven't seen anything anywhere on how to export only a portion of a report. Is this even possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried adding a parameter to your report so that your users can filter the data before they export? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx

Comment: @PaulBambury That's a good idea! However, this report is a bit weird.. It's a way for people to Search like google. They type in 'x' and it looks through the database for anything that has 'x'. Example: Searching 'x' could bring up 1- ID: 'x1' Name: "name" and 2-ID:'new' Name: "NameX". So the user is wanting to be able to export the data provided only for the data that actualy contained their search return.

Comment: That's not problem either. You can use the LIKE operator on a filter to allow wildcard searches. Assuming you have set up a text parameter (MyParam) you can then apply a filter expression on an appropriate column in your dataset (="*" + Parameters!MyParam.Value + "*"). This would then filter the report to show only data that contains the text typed by the user. Have a go with this and see how you get on

Comment: Thanks Paul for all your help! I don't think what I'm trying to do is possible haha. Even once I get to this part the export just doesn't quite work to only show what the user wants due to Groups and stuff. It's probably just too specific of a case =)